# SEND EMAIL on Case in Lightning

Tags: lightning, case-object

I have added activity history to cases as related list and it contains send email button as a related list button, but I dont see send email button in lightning, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In lightning, you will see the email button only in case Feed, if you have enabled Email-To-Case otherwise you will have to create a custom Send Email Action.

Checkout these links for more information [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_send_email_quick_action_considerations.htm&type=5)  and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_email-to-case.htm&type=5)